# creating index mysql for multiple word keywords

Tags: mysql

I have mysql database, i have a table with several columns and one of them contains keywords that i need to search on.

The keywords are in a column grouped within quotation marks like this

```
    ID                    keywords
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    row 1:         "one" "one two"  "one two three" "three four five" "two three one"
    row 2:         "four" "forty four"  "fifty four" "thirty four two" "three four five"
```

So as you can see, each "keyword" can either be a single word or a group of words within a quote, where the words within the quote acts as one keyword.

I want to find out which rows contains the desired key word group.

To match a keyword, the whole quote must match perfectly.

For example, if i want find which rows contains "two" it should return ZERO matches. If i search for "three four five" it should return rows 1 and 2.

There may be thousands of rows like this.

the keyword column is of type TEXT

1. I want to make an index to speed up the search on the keywords column, i see there different type of index like UNIQUE, INDEX, SPATIAL, PRIMARY, FULLTEXT etc. Which on should i choose to do index on the keyword column. What is the MYSQL statement to do it?
2. How do i make MYSQL statement using the index to search for keyword groups

Right now i have this statement to do searching, im not sure if its the best way to do it.

```
  SET @find='three four five';
  SELECT * from table WHERE MATCH (keywords) AGAINST(find IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

Comment: Aren't you looking for an extremely simple query, going off your *"To match a keyword, the whole quote must match perfectly."* ? I.e. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Keywords='some_string';`? This will perform a strict select on the exact match. If you don't type the exact string to match, it will return nothing.

Comment: each line has multiple keyword groups, to match, the whole group within the quotes must match, so maybe using '=' cannot work because multiple keyword groups are on the same line

Comment: I see, then `LIKE` would be the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bad database structure.
But if you cant change the DB now, and need to fetch the result:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE `keywords` LIKE '%"three four five"%'
```

If this variable comes from the user, please use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). and then the query will look like this:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE `keywords` LIKE '%"?"%'
```

Comment: awesome thanks, what about creating an index for the keywords column to speed it up, how do i do that?

Comment: Wouldn't you use a strict equals in the WHERE clause, i.e. `WHERE Keywords='some_string'`? Using `LIKE` would return any instance that contains the word, or am I missing something? Wasn't OP requesting a strict search, where either the string matches 100%, or it doesn't. OP: *To match a keyword, the whole quote must match perfectly.*

Comment: @NickBuck, No, you cant speed this by index, since `LIKE` will try to match against each line. @Martin, The OP asked about getting the exact match. and this is why we must put a **double quote** inside the **single quotes**, so it will also match the beginning and end of the phrase.

Comment: @JonnieJS, so it can never be speeded up by any means? is it doomed to searching the whole database all the time? what if i put each keyword group on a different line, can indexing work with multiple words representing  a single keyword?

Comment: @NickBuck, of course! The whole point of indexing, is that it hashes the value of the cell and can jump to it instantly. then you can remove the quotes, and put each phrase at its own row, and now you can use plain search `WHERE keywords = ?` since it will match the cell exactly. But you said you can't change the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your data model!  Don't store keywords in a single column.  SQL has a great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a *table*.

So, use:

```
create table entityKeywords (
    entityKeywordId int auto_increment primary key,
    entityId int,
    keyword varchar(255),
    unique (entityId, keyword),
    index (keyword)
);
```

Now you can use this table to take advantage of SQL and search for keywords.

Full text capabilities are very powerful . . . but they are really designed for actual text.  Keywords are just a type of attribute on a column, with a 1:n relationship.  It is better to model them using a separate table.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I understand changing the structure would make it better, but unfortunately im unable to change the structure at this time

Comment: if the structure was changed so that each keyword group was on a different row, would i be able to use indexing to speed it up? Can indexing work if there are more than one word to represent a single keyword?

Comment: @NickBuck . . . If the structure were changed, each row would contain one "keyword", however that is defined.  If a keyword had more than one word, then that would be the contents of the `keyword` column.